# EFCore + AutoMapper: update to my object not being saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I just cannot get this to work, and I don't know why. I'm trying to write code that will update an existing Invoice object from the table. The Invoice object has a list of InvoiceItems that should be saved at the same time.

The call to `SaveChanges` actually throws an Exception `The instance of entity type 'InvoiceItem' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value is already being tracked.`

Here is my code. As you can see I am retrieving the existing Invoice by its Id, then I use `AutoMapper` to map all the fields to the existing object. The `request.Invoice` contains the new Invoice object that is to be saved.

```
var existingInvoice = dbContext.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == request.InvoiceId);
if (existingInvoice != null)
{
    mapper.Map(request.Invoice, existingInvoice);

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Can anyone give me a clue what I might be doing wrong? I've read that I can set the `EntityState` to `Detached` for all of my InvoiceItems, but I can hardly imagine I should do this for all of the related objects for all of my Entities when I try to update these. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure why you aren't using `FirstOrDefaultAsync`. My guess is that somehow the entity is getting disconnected from the context, try adding `dbContext.Invoices.Update(existingInvoice)` after your call to `Map`.

Comment: Tried that. Exact same error. Also I have tried both FirstOrDefault() and FirstOrDefaultAsync just to be sure, but both also run into the same exception. Could it be that some other part of the application has selected one or more of the same invoice items while my update is going on and I should look out for something like that?

Comment: Take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore). W/o that extension AM won't map child collection properly.